# xhr() call to sharepoint web part

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to use WinJS.xhr() to get the output of a web part in SharePoint.

I am using Fiddler to dissect the request and I can see the request has 4 actions, the third returns most of the HTML/markup and then the fourth returns data retrieved from the SharePoint underlying data source, and then somewhere it is merged together. However when I view source of the page I do not see the data from the fourth call in the markup - meaning an xhr() call will not include the data I need.

Does anyone have experience getting the full output of a web part control? The goal is to take the data from a web part and display it in a Windows RT application.

Comment: Could you be more specific? SharePoint has so many different versions and Web Parts...

Comment: What specifics do you need? The web part I am trying to retrieve is a Performance Point web part of a dashboard. I am fairly new to SP so not sure what you need. SharePoint 2013